# In which cases numpy's out parameter is faster?

Tags: python, numpy

I am not sure if the out parameter is worth the trouble for my project, so I am doing a series of tests.

But so far, in every case I've tested, the out parameter seems to make the performance slightly slower if not the same as the simpler implementation and I can't figure out why.

here's a example:
`test1` and `test11` are meant to be equivalent but the later uses a n out parameter for avoiding allocating a new array every time.

same for `test2` and `test22`

```py
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

N = 1000

weights = np.arange(N * N).astype('f4').reshape((N, N))

inputs = np.arange(N).astype('f4')

cache_out1 = np.empty((N, N), dtype='f4')
cache_out2 = np.empty(N, dtype='f4')

def test1():
    return (weights * inputs).sum(axis=1)

def test11():
    np.multiply(weights, inputs, out=cache_out1)
    np.sum(cache_out1, axis=1, out=cache_out2)
    return cache_out2

def test2():
    return (weights * inputs[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=0)

def test22():
    np.multiply(weights, inputs[:, np.newaxis], out=cache_out1)
    np.sum(cache_out1, axis=0, out=cache_out2)
    return cache_out2


print('test1:', timeit(test1,  number=1000))
print('test11:', timeit(test11, number=1000))
print('test2:', timeit(test2,  number=1000))
print('test22:', timeit(test22, number=1000))
```

output:

```
test1: 1.1015455439919606
test11: 1.0834621820104076
test2: 1.1083468289871234
test22: 1.1045935050060507
```

Comment: Is it really important for you? feels like premature optimisation

Comment: Specifying the output shape, means that numpy needs to check the shape, and then potentially transpose the matrix, which explains the extra time requirement

Comment: Your output seems to show that using the `out` parameter is slightly faster not slower

Comment: @Chris_Rands it would be important if I could find a case in which the out parameter makes it significantly faster, but with those results, I feel compelled to just go for the simpler alternative.

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, it's slightly slower for smaller values of N like 100 on my machine, but if N is larger it seems to be faster but still negligible.

Comment: what about `weights.dot(inputs)`,  `weights @ inputs` ; `np.einsum('ji,i->j', weights, inputs)`; `np.einsum('ij,j->i', weights, inputs)`; `np.dot(weights, inputs)`; etc etc... Will you measure their speed also cause they are doing exactly the same thing

Comment: @onyambu I just found another algorithm that skips the full matrix multiplication and is about 5x faster, so I'll leave this alone.

Comment: @kalehops what is the algorithm?

Comment: @onyambu I'm using a sparse matrix that is updated stochastically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will make a bigger impact when your arrays are bigger and the allocation time takes longer. Using the `out` parameter would allow you to amortize the allocation time by re-using that memory. To take your example:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

N = 4096

weights = np.arange(N * N).astype('f4').reshape((N, N))

inputs = np.arange(N).astype('f4')

cache_out1 = np.empty((N, N), dtype='f4')
cache_out2 = np.empty(N, dtype='f4')

def test1():
    return (weights * inputs).sum(axis=1)

def test11():
    np.multiply(weights, inputs, out=cache_out1)
    np.sum(cache_out1, axis=1, out=cache_out2)
    return cache_out2

def test2():
    return (weights * inputs[:, np.newaxis]).sum(axis=0)

def test22():
    np.multiply(weights, inputs[:, np.newaxis], out=cache_out1)
    np.sum(cache_out1, axis=0, out=cache_out2)
    return cache_out2


n = 100
print('test1:', timeit(test1,  number=n))
print('test11:', timeit(test11, number=n))
print('test2:', timeit(test2,  number=n))
print('test22:', timeit(test22, number=n))
```

```
test1: 2.5047981239913497
test11: 1.7144565229973523
test2: 2.4683585959865013
test22: 1.6845238849928137
```

Comment: what about `weights.dot(inputs)`,  `weights @ inputs` ; `np.einsum('ji,i->j', weights, inputs)`; `np.einsum('ij,j->i', weights, inputs)`; `np.dot(weights, inputs)`; etc etc... Will you measure their speed also cause they are doing exactly the same thing

Comment: Interesting, it seems to not make a difference for extremelly large or tiny N's. but is faster on those middle values.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to squeeze the last nanoseconds, check Numba or Cython.

Especially if you can parallel the operations, you can get quite important speedups.

Comment: yea, I think I'm going to try it on cython.

Comment: numba is much easier to give it a try, just adding `@njit` decorator. And you can also pre-compile it. Check [the documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html)